# Cracked wood on dresser

Tags: wooden-furniture

So my bedroom dresser is pretty old. I recently have noticed a crack going down one of the slabs of wood. Is the only way to fix this with glue? I want to be able to fix it without replacing any of the wood, because it is handmade and almost impossible to take apart. And sadly I cannot post a photo because when I try, it doesn’t support my software. :(

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of the dresser and the problematic crack? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Has it been moved to a less humid environment / area? Or fitted A/C recently which may have caused the crack?

Comment: I have a similar problem with an old walnut dresser. The standard wood clamps were not enough, so I stopped messing with it. Next step is some rig with a car or truck jack.

Comment: You might consider asking this on the Woodworking Stack Exchange: https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/
At the very least, *please, please, please* if this is a piece of any value (dollars or sentimental) don't try flooding the crack with wood glue or epoxy until you are absolutely certain about what the outcome will be.

Comment: The best way to proceed depends on what caused the crack and where it's at. If it was due to expansion/contraction or damage. Is it two boards once glued coming apart or does the crack stem from a knot.  A photo would be very helpful.

Comment: The crack is not in between 2 boards. However, it’s not stemming from a knot. It may be, but I can’t tell because the dresser is painted. It’s just a long crack going down the middle.

Comment: And, replying to solar mike, the dresser is in the room that my sister and I share. Our house is really old, so there isn’t any ac vents in every room unlike newer houses. So it is possible that the ac could have caused it, because we move one into our window every summer.